# Slow IN() MySQL query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following SQL query which is working great but is very slow to process (3 to 5 seconds). I have created indexes on "slug" and "checksum" columns but as the IN clause runs through 5000 to 10000 rows it's not enough to make it fast.
I read that there was a way to improve it using temporary tables and/or joins but I can't find a way do make it work.

DB engine is InnoDB on MySQL.
Any help would be really appreciated.

```
SELECT name AS personName, 
       slug AS personSlug, 
       COUNT(slug) AS personCount 
  FROM person
 WHERE checksum IN
         ( SELECT checksum 
             FROM person 
            WHERE slug = 'john-doe' )  
   AND NOT (slug = 'john-doe')
 GROUP BY personName 
 ORDER BY personCount DESC
```

Comment: Just an aside, the not-equal operator `x <> y` would be a little more conventional here than `NOT (x = y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully understanding what you query is attempting to do without seeing some sample data. But it looks like you are trying to find all checksums that match the checksums assoicated with 'john-doe' but don't have slug = 'john-doe' - so a search for duplicates of some sort.

The following self-join should do this for you.

```
SELECT
    p.name AS personName,
    p.slug AS personSlug,
    COUNT(p.slug) AS personCount
FROM
    person AS p
INNER JOIN
    person AS p2
ON
    p.checksum = p2.checksum
WHERE
    p2.slug = 'john-doe'
    AND p.slug <> 'john-doe'
GROUP BY personName
ORDER BY personCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It reduced the execution time from 3 to 5 seconds to 300ms!

Comment: @Anthony Did you try the answer of Gordon Linoff? Usually EXISTS is even faster because it short circuit.

Comment: @plax I have tried the answer of Gordon but it did not improve performance.

Comment: @MikeBrant . . . I would guess there is an index on `slug` and the filtering is quite strong.  This probably makes this version more efficient.  My version can't take advantage of it because the `=` filtering is on the subquery, not the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Often changing it to a `not exists` helps performance:

```
SELECT name AS personName, slug AS personSlug, COUNT(slug) AS personCount
FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              from person p2
              WHERE p2.slug = 'john-doe' and p2.checksum = p.checksum
             ) AND
     NOT (slug = 'john-doe')
GROUP BY personName
ORDER BY personCount DESC;
```

For performance you want an index on `person(checksum, slug)`.

Comment: As far as I can see you changed the meaning of the query? Did you mean `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM person WHERE slug = 'john-doe' AND checksum = p.checksum) AND slug <> 'john-doe'`?

Comment: @plaix . . . Yes I did.  You are correct that should be `exists` not `not exists`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. Unfortunately that did not help improving performance (same or surprisingly worst).

Comment: Do you have the index on `checksum, slug` ?

Comment: I do have the index on checksum, slug. I have triple-checked your solution but it still takes the same time or more time to run than my original request.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, a LEFT JOIN is faster than the IN clause and any kind of subquery

```
SELECT p1.name AS personName, p1.slug AS personSlug, COUNT(p1.slug) AS personCount 
FROM person p1
LEFT JOIN person p2 on p1.checksum=p2.checksum and p2.slug = 'john-doe'
WHERE p1.slug != 'john-doe'
AND p2.slug is NOT NULL
GROUP BY personName 
ORDER BY personCount DESC
```

this roughly means: "I want to get the name and slug of persons whose slug is not 'john-doe' for which  there's at least one row with the same checksum with the slug 'john-doe'."

If you want to find the records for which there isn't a matching 'john-doe' record, then you just need to change one clause:

```
SELECT p1.name AS personName, p1.slug AS personSlug, COUNT(p1.slug) AS personCount 
FROM person p1
LEFT JOIN person p2 on p1.checksum=p2.checksum and p2.slug = 'john-doe'
WHERE p1.slug != 'john-doe'
AND p2.slug iS NULL
GROUP BY personName 
ORDER BY personCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's working great. INNER JOIN (see Mike's answer) works as well and from what I have been able to test performances are similar. But maybe LEFT JOIN are better?

Comment: I used LEFT JOIN because I was confused about what you needed to retrieve. If you wanted to find the non matching checksums then LEFT JOIN allows to do that (hence my second query). Performance differences between INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN tend to be negligible for small tables and consistent indexes. If you operate over more than 100.000 records you might want to start benchmarking both.